# Jquery getting all the matching current html data

Tags: javascript, jquery

- In the below html 'return_fly26' is repeated 2 times. So i want the
  matching html with class '**return_fly26**'

---

```
<div class="col-xs-12 nopadding return_fly26">
<div class="col-xs-4 noleftpadding ">

<div class="col-xs-6 norightpadding movies">
<img src="d.gif" alt="App Logo">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 flightinformation">

<p class="ddd">ssss</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5 noleftpadding">

<p class="timings">ssss</p>
<p class="stops">01 h : 30 m</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 nopadding return_fly26">
<div class="col-xs-4 noleftpadding ">

<div class="col-xs-6 norightpadding movies">
<img src="d.gif" alt="App Logo">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 flightinformation">

<p class="ddd">ssss</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5 noleftpadding">

<p class="timings">ssss</p>
<p class="stops">01 h : 30 m</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Below is how i tried

```
$(".onward_fly").html("");
 var owner = $('.return_fly'+flight_id).html();
console.log(owner);
```

If i console it i am getting one one div matching matching with **.return_fly26**. Can any one suggest this !!!!!!

Expected output should be same as above using jquery.

> O/p:

---

```
<div class="col-xs-12 nopadding return_fly26">
<div class="col-xs-4 noleftpadding ">

<div class="col-xs-6 norightpadding movies">
<img src="d.gif" alt="App Logo">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 flightinformation">

<p class="ddd">ssss</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5 noleftpadding">

<p class="timings">ssss</p>
<p class="stops">01 h : 30 m</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 nopadding return_fly26">
<div class="col-xs-4 noleftpadding ">

<div class="col-xs-6 norightpadding movies">
<img src="d.gif" alt="App Logo">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 flightinformation">

<p class="ddd">ssss</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5 noleftpadding">

<p class="timings">ssss</p>
<p class="stops">01 h : 30 m</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [jQuery selectors API](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Proper code is this:

```
 // gets collection
 var myDivs = $('div.return_fly26');
```

Comment: to expand on this, .html() is a method to runs on a single element (first element) in the collection of objects, most jquery methods would do that.